# How to convert text to jsonb entirely for a postgresql column

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

What I have is a text column in Postgresql which I want to convert to JSONB column.

What I have tried is this:

1. `CREATE TABLE test (id serial, sec text, name text);`
2. `INSERT INTO test (id, sec, name) VALUES (1,'{"gender":"male","sections":{"a":1,"b":2}}','subject');`
3. `ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN sec TYPE JSONB USING sec::JSONB;`

This did convert the text column to `jsonb`.

However, if I try to query:

```
 SELECT sec->>'sections'->>'a' FROM test
```

I get an error.

I see the conversion is done only at one level(i.e: sec->>'sections' works fine).

The query `SELECT pg_typeof(name->>'sections') from test;` gives me column type as text.

Is there a way I can convert the text to jsonb entirely, such that I can query `SELECT sec->>'sections'->>'a' FROM test;` successfully?

I don't want to convert the text to json in the query like below, as I need to create index on 'a' later.

```
select (sec->>'sections')::json->>'a' from test;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operator `->>` gives a text as a result. Use `->` if you want `jsonb`:

```
select 
    pg_typeof(sec->>'sections') a,
    pg_typeof(sec->'sections') b
from test;

  a   |   b   
------+-------
 text | jsonb
(1 row)
```

Use:

```
select sec->'sections'->>'a' 
from test;
```

Answer (score 4):

Or better, yet, use the [operator **`#>>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE):

```
SELECT sec #>> '{sections,a}' FROM test;
```

And to use this in an expression index you need extra parentheses:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON test ((sec #>> '{sections,a}'));
```

Make sure to use a matching expression (without parentheses) in queries to allow index usage.